# Repair Wix associated file exentions

Tags: wix, registry, windows-installer

I have a WIX installer for product A which sets up the file associations for certain file types, if user installs another program (product B) it overwrites those extensions to the new program (B).

If I run repair for Product A it is unable to reset the file associations to 'A'

First of all, will repair be able to do this? How should it be configured to enable repair to do this?

Thanks